# GNU JavaMail: No provider for address: rfc822

Tags: java, ant, jakarta-mail

Using OpenJDK 1.7.0 and GNU JavaMail 1.1.2.

During the actual message send call:

```
SMTPTransport.send(msg);
```

This happens:

```
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for address: rfc822
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:641)
    at javax.mail.Transport.doSend(Transport.java:149)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:75)
```

Transport.send(msg) produces the same result.

I'm pretty sure my classpath is OK. Here's how it's defined in build.xml in the JAR task:

```
<zipfileset src="${sys}/inetlib.jar" includes="**/*.java **/*.class"/>
<zipfileset src="${sys}/gnumail-providers.jar" includes="**/*.java **/*.class"/>
<zipfileset src="${sys}/gnumail.jar" includes="**/*.java **/*.class"/>
```

Where ${sys} is /usr/share/java. Am I going to have to suck it up and use the Oracle JavaMail API?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem as you and it happened to be caused by the jar `geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec` messing things up. A simple solution is to exclude it from your dependencies. With Maven, assuming it's a dependency from CXF:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.5</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

As to know exactly why, I did not took the time to investigate further. It's a multi-thread safety bug for sure (I got it when multiple threads where speaking SMTP at the same time).

Original reference of the solution [here](http://www.devsumo.com/technotes/2014/03/javamail-random-nosuchproviderexception-errors-sending-smtp-mail/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your program is trying to set rfc822 as the domain address to be used for the transport layer. Is this a valid address? I suggest searching your code for this reference as the problem is undoubtedly around that area.